Error when archiving files in the CI/CD pipeline: error at the last step after transferring files to the archive (GitLab CI)
When archiving files using pipeline, I get the following error:
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
But at the same time, he transferred all the files to the archive
This is what my pipeline looks like:
.generate_package:
  image: registry.tomskasu.ru/gs-platform-team/gs-deploy-collector/rpm-builder:latest
  stage: archive
  variables:
    SERVER_FOLDER_NAME: "NAME of server" # Имя сервера
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ./mnt
  script:
    - echo "Generating package for $SERVER_FOLDER_NAME"
    - cd /opt/deploy/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$SERVER_FOLDER_NAME
    - tar -hcvf ../../$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$SERVER_FOLDER_NAME.tar *
    - cd /opt/deploy/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
  timeout: 4h

This is how I call it in my additional pipeline file:
generate_package_main:
  variables:
    SERVER_FOLDER_NAME: "MAIN"
  extends:
    - .generate_package

All files are available and need permissions
